# FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null Xamarin Android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented the below code in two projects, one works and the other does not work ,below is the code. i have checked other posts which says to use `com.google.gms:google-services` i have added `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.basement` still it gives error, which GooglePlayServices plugin should i use for Xamarin ?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

       Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);


       Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

       buttonView = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
       error = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.error);

       buttonView.Click += StartQueryDetailsAsync;
}





public async void StartQueryDetailsAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object> user = new Dictionary<string, Java.Lang.Object>
        {
             { "PurchaseToken", purchase.PurchaseToken },
             { "QueryNumber", 1}
        };

        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.Instance;
           firestore.Collection("DineUser").Document(purchase.Id).Set(user).AddOnSuccessListener(this);
}
```

**Error:**

```
{Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method) [0x00068] in <8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0 at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod) [0x0000e] in <957bbfdfda4341e2939c881206c1140a>:0 at Firebase.Firestore.FirebaseFirestore.get_Instance () [0x0002f] in <97744bd4f3f740c1884b76e44794b938>:0 at DineCam.Main.DrawRect+<Purchase>d__56.MoveNext () [0x00417] in D:\DineCam\DineCam\Main\DrawRect.cs:427 --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.zze(Unknown Source) at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(Unknown Source) at md580a1eddd40074c89f21a5ec99d8b044c.DrawRect.n_onActivityResult(Native Method) at md580a1eddd40074c89f21a5ec99d8b044c.DrawRect.onActivityResult(DrawRect.java:86) at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508) at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3925) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3972) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) }
```

Comment: Which nuget version of the Play Services are you installing? If it is an older one due to some other dependency in your app, then review this issue as there are several workarounds available: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/104#issuecomment-408878303

Comment: Tried this ,it reads everything from *google-services.json* file except the *ProjectId* . it gives the error *Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev)*. and i am using v60.1142.1 of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement

Comment: Have you try manually assigning everything? : https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/104#issuecomment-406681123

Comment: tried same error *Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).*

Comment: don't know why it works in one project and not in another ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.basement** and **Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore** versions from **v60.1142.1** stable version to **v71.1500.0-preview1** and all **Xamarin.Android.Support** libraries to **v28.0.0.1** and it works now, previously my project was not allowing to install preview version, i created a new project and added the preview versions and it works now.